# Why are my temporary AWS credentials from an Identity Pool unauthorized?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have an Identity Pool which has an Authenticated Role. One of the policies on that role is to have Full Invoke Access to API Gateway Endpoints. When I create temporary credentials with `AWS.config.credentials.get()`, I create an instance of the API Gateway client like so.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var newClientCredentials = {
                accessKey: accessKey,
                secretKey: secretKey
            };

apiClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(newClientCredentials);
apiClient.myendpointPost({}, postRequest, requestParams).then(function(result) {console.log(result)});
```

I've double checked that `accessKey` and `secretKey` are set. When I make a call with `apiClient` to my endpoint, I get an `unauthorized` response from the Gateway.

My questions:

- Is there a way to check that the temporary credentials (`accessKey` and `secretKey`) are for the appropriate Authenticated Role?
- Is it possible to find out why API Gateway is rejecting these credentials (maybe something I can log to CloudWatch)?

Comment: you have to pass session token along with access key and secret key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ninad pointed out in the comments I forgot to pass in the session as well with the keys. However, one key step that I had missed was that the Authorization on the endpoint I was hitting had to be set to `AWS_IAM`. I had previously set it to Cognito and pointed to the User Pool, which was not correct.